Why does this error show although the excel sheet has a worksheet and is not corrupted?
Trying to collate the data from two worksheets with a specific naming convention. The code is able to identify the excel files, but it keeps returning: Study Test/Participant 1/text_export_P1S1T2.xlsx: Worksheet index 0 is invalid, 0 worksheets found.
Below is the code that I used:
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from datetime import datetime
import warnings

# Suppress specific warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=UserWarning, module='openpyxl')

# Directory containing the participant folders
home_dir = os.getcwd()

# Standardized increment and stance phase conversion
X2 = np.linspace(0, 100, 101)  # Standardized to 101 points for interpolation

# Prepare to collect results in a single DataFrame
consolidated_results = []

def process_file(filepath):
    # Load Excel file
    try:
        df = pd.read_excel(filepath, skiprows=9, engine='openpyxl')
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error reading {filepath}: {e}")
        return None  # Return None if there's an error

    # Check if expected columns are present
    if df.shape[1] < 51:  # Ensure there are at least 51 columns
        print(f"Expected columns not found in {filepath}. Found columns: {df.shape[1]}")
        return None

    # Extract relevant columns
    T = df.iloc[:, 1].dropna().values  # Time (s)
    COP1x = df.iloc[:, 49].dropna().values  # Filtered COP x (mm)
    COP1y = df.iloc[:, 50].dropna().values  # Filtered COP y (mm)
    
    # Normalize time to 0-100 for Stance Phase
    if len(T) < 2:  # Need at least two points to calculate min and max
        print(f"Not enough time points in {filepath}. Found points: {len(T)}")
        return None
    
    Tmin, Tmax = np.min(T), np.max(T)
    SP = (T - Tmin) * (100 / (Tmax - Tmin))

    # Interpolate data
    interp_func = lambda y: interp1d(SP, y, kind='cubic', fill_value="extrapolate")(X2)
    return {
        'Stance Phase (%)': X2,
        'COP1x (mm)': interp_func(COP1x),
        'COP1y (mm)': interp_func(COP1y)
    }

participants = [
    1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12
]

# Iterate through each participant folder and process files
for participant in participants:
    participant_folder = f"Participant {participant}"
    participant_path = os.path.join(home_dir, participant_folder)
    
    for file in os.listdir(participant_path):
        if file.startswith("text_export") and file.endswith(".xlsx"):
            # Process file
            filepath = os.path.join(participant_path, file)
            processed_data = process_file(filepath)
            
            if processed_data is not None:  # Only append if processing was successful
                # Append data to consolidated results
                for i in range(len(processed_data['COP1x (mm)'])):
                    consolidated_results.append({
                        'COP1x (mm)': processed_data['COP1x (mm)'][i],
                        'COP1y (mm)': processed_data['COP1y (mm)'][i]
                    })

# Convert the results to a DataFrame and save to an Excel file
if consolidated_results:  # Only save if there's data to save
    consolidated_df = pd.DataFrame(consolidated_results)
    output_filename = f"Consolidated_Results_{datetime.now().strftime('%y%m%d')}.xlsx"
    consolidated_df.to_excel(output_filename, index=False)
    print(f"Consolidated data saved to {output_filename}")
else:
    print("No data to save.")

I have tried to create an test excel file to see if it's my pandas problem, but it was able to create an excel file.
